# Understanding a basic permutation problem

Tags: probability, permutations

I am failing to wrap my head around a solution to a rather basic problem:

> At a party, ***n*** men and ***m*** women put their drinks on a table and go out on the floor
> to dance. When they return, none of them recognizes his or her drink, so everyone
> takes a drink at random. What is the probability that each *man* selects his own
> drink?

The solution is: $$\frac{m!}{(n+m)!}$$

From what I intuit, $n!$ is the total permutations of the drinks among the men, and the above solution is the probability that all men get *another* man's drink, not necessarily that each one gets his *own*.

My solution was, there is a $\frac{1}{n+m}$ probability of the first man getting his drink, then $\frac{1}{n+m-1}$ for the second, $\frac{1}{n+m-2}$ for the third, ... , $\frac{1}{m+1}$ for the $n^{th}$. Resulting in a probability of $\prod\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{n+m-i}$.

Can someone explain their thinking when approaching this problem?

**EDIT**

Issue arose from confusing variables and failing to identify that $$
\begin{align}
\frac{m!}{(n+m)!} &= \frac{m!}{(n+m)(n+m-1)...(n+m-(n-1))(m!)}\\
&= \prod\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{n+m-i}\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: The total number of permutations is $(n+m)!$.  The number of permutations which leave the men unchanged is $m!$

Comment: @lulu Sorry, I misread the solution. It is equal to $\prod_{i = 0}^{n - 1}\frac 1{n + m - i}$.

Comment: @lulu can you elaborate on "The number of permutations which leave the men unchanged is m!" part. My understanding is that m! are the total permutations of men's drinks, not necessarily unchanged.

Comment: There's one way to leave the men unchanged, and $m!$ ways to permute the women.

Comment: Your notation is (a little) confusing, since you use $m$ to denote the number of women.  If you fix the $n$ "male" drinks,  then you can only permute the $m$ "female" drinks, hence there are $m!$ ways to do it.

Comment: @lulu Ah yes, I confused the variables! My apologies! The solution makes a bit more sense now. My next concern then, is what is wrong with my proposed solution?

Comment: Is there something wrong with it ?  $\frac {m!}{(n+m)!}=\frac 1{(m+1)(m+2)\cdots (m+n)}$ .  Isn't that the same as your product?

Comment: @lulu The world is right side up again. Not familiar enough with factorials apparently -- I expanded it wrong on paper, leading to a mismatch. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How many ways can you rearrange all the drinks?  Answer:  (m+n)!

Suppose all the men kept their drinks and only the women’s drinks got mixed up.  How many possibilities are for this arrangement?  Since there are m women, the answer is m!

So the odds of the men keeping their drinks is m! / (m+n)!

Comment: Elegant, clear, direct, and to the point. (+1).

Comment: I think this is key insight -- remember to account for all groups pertaining to the problem, not just the one in question. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

*Notes:* The most directly 'Relevant' of the links in the margin seems to be [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33134/matching-hats-and-coats-problem?rq=1), which also discusses a Poisson approximation. Also, [an answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146268/is-there-a-way-to-check-the-correctness-of-your-answer-to-a-probability-question?rq=1) discusses simulation of a similar problem, but explanations of the Perl program seem sparse. [Other links discuss probabilities for the (simpler) classical problem of derangements of items of a single type.]

---

**Comment:** Simulation approximates your suggested answer (+1), @Lulu's Comment, and @NicNic8's Answer (+1), for a specific case.

Suppose the population consists of $n = 3$ men (numbered 101, 102, 103). and $n = 4$ women (numbered from 1 through 4).
Then the answer is $4!/7! = 0.00476.$

If we permute the population a million times and take the total score `s` of the population elements that
are in their correct positions, then the total
will exceed 300 precisely when all three men
get their own drinks. The proportion of a million scores exceeding $300$ should approximate the desired probability to about
three places.

```
set.seed(2021)
pop = c(1:4, 101:103)
pop
[1]   1   2   3   4 101 102 103

set.seed(2021)
s = replicate(10^6, sum(pop[sample(pop)==pop]))
mean(s > 300)
[1] 0.004821      # aprx 4!/7!
2 * sd(s > 300)/1000
[1] 0.0001385318  # aprx 95% margin of sim error
```

So the simulated value is $0.0048\pm 0.00014$ which includes $4!/7!.$

*Notes:* Demo of R code for one permutation:

```
set.seed(1234)         # for reproducibility
a = sample(pop); a     # permute sample
[1]   1   4 102   3 101   2 103
b = (a == pop); b      # in proper order?
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
c = pop[a == pop];  c  # list who got own drinks
[1]   1 101 103        # two men got own drinks
sum(c)
[1] 205                # score
```